# how to create setup for objectarx plugin

Tags: objectarx

I have a class library project in c#,my project is a plug-in for AutoCAD,in this project I used objectArx,now how can I correct that after installing a setup that I can not use this plug-in for AutoCAD, please give me tips.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this link on creating Plugins is useful : 
[Auto Loader Whitepaper](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html)

If not, please provide some detailed information on what's not working.